# trying to have a dynamic textview

Tags: android

I'm trying to have a dynamic textview based on the xml file.....
Please help me with my code

**CODE**

MessageViewPage.java

```
package com.dpn.pack;

public class MessageViewPage extends Activity {

TextView tv1=new TextView(this);
ScrollView sv;
String nickname,body;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.message_view_page);

    Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();

    nickname= b.getString("nick");
    body=b.getString("body");

    LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View v = vi.inflate(R.layout.message_view_page, null);

    // fill in any details dynamically here
    TextView textView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textViewSender);
    textView.setText("Sender : "+nickname);

    // insert into main view
    View insertPoint = findViewById(R.id.textViewSender);
    insertPoint.addView(v, 0, new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));

}

}
```

my **XML** file as follows

message_view_page.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="5dp" 
android:background="@drawable/view">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewSender"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="20dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewBody"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textViewSender"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textViewSender"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    android:textSize="15dp"
    android:textColor="#F69DD1" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonReply"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="45dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
    android:text="Reply" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonListen"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="45dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
    android:text="LIsten" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I am having an error in this code

```
insertPoint.addView(v, 0, new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
```

like

[image]
Please any one tell me the solution for my problem.

my target output demo like

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have a duplicate parameter:

```
ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT
```

Try:

```
ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT
```

Answer (score 0):

I could be mistaken, as you show where the error is but do not say what it actually is.
So try instead of passing `v` to `addView()` method, to pass your `textView`.

Something like this: `insertPoint.addView(textView, 0, ...)`